# How do I build the Python documentation locally?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I made some changes to the Python documentation that I would like to submit a merge request with. But before I do that I want to build the documentation into HTML locally to make sure it looks right. How do I do that?

Comment: https://devguide.python.org/documenting/#building-the-documentation

Answer (score 1):

You need to

```
cd Doc/
```

instead of the top level `cpython/` source code directory, then the [README file in that directory](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Doc/README.rst) explains the process:

Install the dependencies:

```
pip install sphinx blurb python-docs-theme
```

and then run

```
make html
```

The docs will be built into `Doc/build/html`. You can serve them locally with

```
make serve
```

Then you should see the locally-built version of the docs at http://localhost:8000/